# uipageviewController : how is the index found in this code?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I don't understand how `indexOfVC` returns an index: the dataObject is an optional in the `ContentViewController` :

```
class ContentViewController : UIViewController {

var dataObject:AnyObject?
```

, and when we invoke `indexOfVC`, pageContent contains html strings. How the dataObject can be found in pageContent if dataObject is empty, and pageContent is filled with html text ?

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index:Int)->ContentViewController?{
    if (index < 0) || (index >= pageContent.count){
        return nil
    }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as ContentViewController
    vc.dataObject = pageContent[index]
    return vc
}

/* HERE */
func indexOfVC(viewController:ContentViewController) ->Int {
    if let dataObject : AnyObject = viewController.dataObject {
        return pageContent.indexOfObject(dataObject)
    }
    else {
        return NSNotFound
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index : Int = indexOfVC(viewController as ContentViewController)
    println("after: index: \(index)") //found 0, then 1, 2,... when scrolling right
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }
    index++
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

//called in viewdidload
func createContentPages(){
    var pageStrings = [String]()
    for i in 1...11 {
        pageStrings.append(String("<html><head></head><body><br><h1>Chapter \(i)</h1><p>This is the page \(i) of content displayed using UIPageViewController in iOS 8.</p></body></html>"))
    }
    pageContent = pageStrings
}
```

The code is from : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_UIPageViewController_Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `dataObject` is never nil at the time that `indexOfVC` is called.  Although it is optional, and will be nil when the `ContentViewController` is first initialised, as soon as the `viewControllerAtIndex` method creates a ContentViewController, it sets its `dataObject` to one of the elements of the `pageContent` array:

```
var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as ContentViewController
vc.dataObject = pageContent[index]
```

So the overall flow is:

1. The starting page is set in the `viewDidLoad` of the main view controller:

   ```
   let startingViewController: ContentViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(0)!
   ```

   This creates a VC and sets its `dataObject` to `pageContent[0]`.
2. If you then swipe, the pageViewController will call `viewControllerAfterViewControler:viewController`.  In this call, the `viewController` argument is the **current** view controller.  The method needs to know the index of the current VC, so it calls `indexOfVC` with `viewController` as the argument.
3. `indexOfVC` reads the `dataObject` value for that view controller, which is `pageContent[0]`.  Hence `pageContent.indexOfObject(dataObject)` returns the integer 0.
4. This is then incremented (`index++`) and so the call to `viewControllerAtIndex` will create a new VC for index 1.  This will create a new view controller and immediately set its `dataObject` to pageContent[1].  And the cycle continues...

So as currently coded, `indexOfVC` is **never** passed a viewController where its `dataObject` is nil.  But if it ever were, it would return the special value `NSNotFound`.  Then `viewControllerAfterViewController:` checks the return value and, if it **is** `NSNotFound`, returns `nil` - which tells the page view controller not to permit the swipe.